# What is the difference between Type and Class?

Tags: language-agnostic, class, programming-languages, types, glossary

What makes a type different from class and vice versa?

(In the general language-agnostic sense)

Comment: Effective C++, Item 19: Treat class design as type design.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The following answer is from Gof book ([Design Patterns](https://amazon.co.uk/dp/0201633612))

> An object's **class** defines how the
> object is implemented. The class
> defines object's internal state and
> the implementation of its
> operations.

> In contrast, an object's
> **type** only refers to its interface - a
> set of requests to which it can
> respond.

> An object can have many types,
> and objects of different classes can
> have the same type.

```
//example in c++
template<typename T> 
const T & max(T const &a,T const &b)
{
return a>b?a:b;  //> operator of the type is used for comparison
}
```

max function requires a type with **operation >** with its own type as one of it interface any class that satisfies the above requirement can be used to generate specific max<particular class/primitive type> function for that class.

Answer (score 65):

I always think of a 'type' as an umbrella term for 'classes' and 'primitives'.

`int foo; // Type is int, class is nonexistent.`

`MyClass foo; // Type is MyClass, class is MyClass`

Comment: Well, in .NET it should be the same, even primitives are classes (or more exactly structs).

Comment: @dalle: agreed, there is no inherent difference between type and class. Eddie's example is very C++/Java dependent. It's not at all THE definition.

Comment: I imagine it will be hard to get "THE" definition of a 'type' versus a class.  So many languages have their own typing system.

One definition I heard for .NET was that a 'type' includes both ref and value types, whereas a class is only used to describe ref types.

Comment: Isn't int just a short-hand for System.Int32 kind of? In other words: int foo; // Type is int, class is System.Int32 ?

Comment: What if there are no primitives, e.g. in Smalltalk. What's difference between class and type then?

Comment: @Svish, ages late but just for other readers: `Int32` is a `struct`, at least in C#.

Answer (score 64):

Inspired by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29)...

In **type theory** terms;

- A **type** is an abstract interface.
  Types generally represent nouns, such as a person, place or thing, or something nominalized,
- A **class** represents an implementation of the type.
  It is a concrete data structure and collection of subroutines

  Different concrete classes can produce objects of the same abstract type (depending on type system).

  *For example, one might implement the *type* `Stack` with two *classes*: `SmallStack` (fast for small stacks, but scales poorly) and `ScalableStack` (scales well but high overhead for small stacks).*

  Similarly, a given class may have several different **constructors**.

> [image]
>
> The banana example.
>
> - A `Banana` *type* would represent the properties and functionality of bananas in general.
> - The `ABCBanana` and `XYZBanana` *classes* would represent ways of producing bananas.
>     (Different banana suppliers in real life, or different data structures and functions to represent and draw bananas in a video game).
>
>   The `ABCBanana` class could then produce particular bananas which are 
>     ***instances*** of the `ABCBanana` *class*, they would be ***objects* of *type* Banana**.

It is not rare the programmer provide a single and only implementation for a type. In this case the *class* name is often identical with the *type name*. But there is still a type (which could be extracted in an interface if required), and an implementation (which would implement the separate interface) which builds instances (objects) of the class.

Answer (score 18):

Type is the umbrella term for all the available object templates or concepts. A class is one such object template. So is the structure type, the Integer type, the Interface type etc. These are all types

If you want, you can look at it this way: A type is the parent concept. All the other concepts: Class, Interface, Structure, Integer etc inherit from this concept.i.e They are types

Answer (score 10):

Taken from the GoF citation from below:

> An objects's **class** defines how the
> object is implemented .The class
> defines the object's internal state and
> the implementation of its
> operations.
>
> In contrast, an objects's
> **type** only refers to its interface - the
> set of requests to which it can
> respond.

I want to provide an example using Java:

```
public interface IType {
}

public class A implements IType {
    public A{};
}

public class B implements IType {
    public B{};
}
```

Both classes `A` and `B` implement the interface and thus are of the type `IType`. Additionally in Java, both classes produce their own type (respectively to their class name). Thus the class `A` is of type `A` **and** `IType` and the class `B` is of type `B` **and** `IType` satisfying:

> An object can have many types,
> and objects of different classes can
> have the same type.

The difference between subtypes and subclass probably helps to understand that issue as well:

https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall98/cs441/mainus/node12.html

Comment: "*Both classes `A` and `B` implement the interface and thus are of the type `IType`*", I don't think so. Classes `A` and `B` are not of type `IType`, simply because they don't behave like an object described by `IType`. Type relates to objects, not to classes. Classes `A` and `B` are *implementations* of type `IType`, aimed to produce objects of type `IType` in different ways (the object code and data structures are different, but satisfy `IType` specifications). A class can generally implement several types, and therefore can produce objects of different types.

Answer (score 6):

In *general language-agnostic* sense - **Class** is an *realization* of the **Type**.

Often when this is the *only* realization of that type, you can use both terms to reference it in some context.

On the contrary, for example, in C# context - **Class** is just *one* of the [many more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/types) *implementations* of a **Type** concept like primitives, structs, pointers etc.

Answer (score 4):

Type is conceptually a superset of class.  In the broader sense, a class is one form of type.

Closely related to classes are interfaces, which can bee seen as a very special kind of class - a purely abstract one.  These too are types.

So "type" encompasses classes, interfaces and in most languages primitives too.  Also platforms like the dot-net CLR have structure types too.

Comment: rajKumar, your question is quite ambiguous. do you as about "type" as a feature of some language, or as a general concept?

Comment: Not all user-defined types are classes though, at least not in all languages.

Comment: jalf, agree it is a wrong characteristics. interface is user-defined too, and there can be no user-defined types. Class is a specialized type serving special needs (creating instances of objects)

Comment: An interface is simply a special type, a purely abstract class - it's still a type (in the greater sense).

Comment: Software Monkey, interface is not a purely abstract class - it is a special concept. "user-defined" is not a defining property of classes

Comment: It's a *specialized* kind of class, but it is still a kind of class.  (Java even compiles an interface to a class object with the same internal structure because it's a difference in conceptual program design, not in actuality).

Comment: Software Monkey, it is hard to argue but I wouldn't treat interface as a subset of classes. IMO defining property of class is ability to create objects, interfaces can not be used for it. Both of them can define contracts but interface can't define behavior.

Comment: @Aku: Fair enough; but you must concur that they both define types.

Comment: @Software Monkey, yes interfaces and classes are types and can be used to define new types. Only reason I commented on you post is that I don't agree that "user-defined" can be used as a defining characteristic.

Comment: @Aku: And I edited my answer to clarify that.  I never intended to say being user-defined is a defining characteristic - you inferred that.

Comment: @Software Monkey it is my mistake then. Talking about low-level conceptions is never easy :)

Comment: @Aku: But very helpful I find - one's thinking is, challenged, clarified, and often altered.

Answer (score 4):

Type contains description of the data (i.e. properties, operations, etc),

Class is a specific type - it is a template to create instances of [objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(object-oriented_programming)).

Strictly speaking class is a special concept, it can be seen as a package containing subset of [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) describing some aspects of an object.

For example in C# you can find interfaces and classes. Both of them are types, but interface can only define some contract and can not be instantiated unlike classes.

Simply speaking *class* is a *specialized type* used to encapsulate properties and behavior of an object.

Wikipedia can give you a more complete answer:

- [Definition of class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_science))
- [Definition of data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type)

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate it the fastest way:

A Struct is a Type, but a Struct is not a Class.

As you can see, a Type is an "abstract" term for not only definitions of classes, but also structs and primitive data types like float, int, bool.

Comment: It would be fine to mention the .net CLR as an *example* of a framework in which there exist types that are not classes (Java could be cited as another, though .net has more kinds of types).  An extra little wrinkle in .net, though, is that `Type` (capitalized as shown) is the short name of a system class (`System.Type`) which is used to hold descriptions of types.

Answer (score 3):

I think of a type as being the set of things you can do with a particular value. For instance, if you have an integer value, you can add it to other integers (or perform other arithmetic operations), or pass it to functions which accept an integer argument. If you have an object value, you can call methods on it that are defined by its class.

Because a class defines what you can do with objects of that class, a class defines a type. A class is more than that though, since it also provides a description of how the methods are implemented (something not implied by the type) and how the fields of the object are laid out.

Note also that an object value can only have one class, but it may have multiple types, since every superclass provides a subset of the functionality available in the object's class.

So although objects and types are closely related, they are really not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

**Type** generally refers to the classification of primitive values - integers, strings, arrays, booleans, null, etc. Usually, you can't create any new types.

**Class** refers to the named set of properties and methods which an object is associated with when it is created. You can usually define as many new classes as you want, although some languages you have to create a new object and then attach methods to it.

This definition is mostly true, but some languages have attempted to combine types and classes in various ways, with various beneficial results.

Comment: In even the type impoverished language C you can create new types, but it has nothing like what people normally think of as classes except in so much as structs, records, and classes all sort-of resemble each other.

Answer (score 3):

To add another example of distinction:  in C++ you have pointer and reference types which can refer to classes, but are not classes in and of themselves.

```
Bar b; // b is of type "class Bar"
Bar *b2 = &b; // b2 is of type "pointer to Class Bar"
Bar &b3 = b; // b3 is of type "reference to Class Bar"
Bar *b4[7]; // b4 is of type "7-element array of pointers to Class Bar"
Bar ***b5; //b5 is of type "pointer to a pointer to a pointer to Class Bar"
```

Note that only one class is involved, but a near infinite number of types can be used.  In some languages, function are considered "first-class-objects" in which case, the type of a function is a class.  In others, the type of a function is merely a pointer.  Classes generally have the concepts of being able to hold data, as well as operations on that data.

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts are pretty much in line with aku's answer.

I see classes as a template for building objects, while types are a way to classify those objects, and provide us with an interface to them.

Python also adds metaclasses, that are just a mechanism to build classes, in the same way as classes build objects (and well, classes and metaclasses are both objects).

[This response](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2079#comment-25536) to the same question in lamba the ultimate seems to me like a perfect explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Types in C, like Int Float, char etc define data that can be acted on with specific methods that can operate on them.  It's no more complicated than that.  Like for int I can add, subtract multiply and maybe divide.  Those are my methods (or operations) for int.  A Class is simply a definition of a new type.  I first define what the data looks like.  Maybe its a single bit.  Maybe it's two words like a complex with a real and imaginary part.  Or maybe its this complex thingy with 309734325 bytes representing the atomic makeup of a weird particle on Jupiter.  I don't care.  Just like an integer, I get to make up the operations I can do with this new data type.  In the case of the integer I had add, subtract, etc.  With this new data type I can define whatever operations I think make sense.  They might be add subtract etc.  but they may add other things.  These are whatever methods I decide to add to my class.

The bottom line is that with a type in C, you have a definition of what the data is, ie; a byte, word, float, char etc.  But any of these also implies what operations are legal and will produce reliable results.

A class is no different except it is up to you to define the interface and acceptable operations.  The class defines these things and when you instantiate it in an Object it defines the behavior of the object just like a type definition defines the behavior of an integer when you operate on it.

Classes just give you the flexibility to define new types and everything about how they operate.

Once this is defined, every time I instantiate an object of class "thingy", it has the data structure I defined and the operations (methods) that I said you can do with it.  The class "thingy" is clearly nothing more or less than a new type that C++ lets me define.

Answer (score 2):

Types and classes are related but not identical. My take is that classes are used for implementation inheritance, whereas types are used for runtime substitution.

[Here](http://ocw.mit.edu/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-170Fall-2005/915D0C58-87BE-46B4-893A-42CFCA08A717/0/lec14.pdf) is a link explaining the *substitution principle* and why subclasses and subtypes are not always the same thing (in Java for example). The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) page on covariance and contravariance has more information on this distinction.

Answer (score 1):

In langugages like Haskell, the concept of Class doesn't exist. It only has Types. (And **Type Class**. Not to be confused with *Class*, **Type Class** is more of an abstracted version of Type).

Monad is a **Type Class**.

```
class Monad m where
  (>>=)  :: m a -> (  a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>)   :: m a ->  m b         -> m b
  return ::   a                 -> m a
  fail   :: String -> m a
```

From a (pure) functional programming perspective, Type is more fundemental than Class as one can trace its root to [Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) (e.g. from a PTL perspective, lambda calculus with types and without types behave quite differently), while Class is really just a construct to enable OO.

In languages that only support Type and don't support Class, functions are often treated as first-class citizen.

Meanwhile, when a language makes a distinction between Type and Class, functions are more of a second-class citizens that can be attached to Objects, etc.  And yup, often you can attach a function onto a Class itself (aka a static function).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I think aku's answer is spot on. Take the java `ArrayList` class as an example

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

An instance of the `ArrayList` class is said to be of type of every superclass it extends and every interface it implements. Therefore, an instance of the `ArrayList` class has a type `ArrayList`, `RandomAccess`, `Cloneable`, and so forth. In other words, values (or instances) belong to one or more types, classes define what these types are.

Answer (score 0):

**Different classes may describe the same type.**

Type consists of these parts:

1. Operations = syntax
2. Description of operations = semantics

Class consists of these parts:

1. Operations = syntax
2. Implementation (= various implementations describe same semantics)

Some notes:

- Interface (as in Java) is not type, because it does not describe semantics (describes only syntax)
- Subclass is not subtype, because subclass may change semantics defined in superclass, subtype cannot change supertype semantics (see Liskov Substitution Principle, e.g. [this LSP example](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, as there are languages with type system that are not OO programming languages, *type* must be a broader concept than *class*

Even in languages like Java, `int` is a (primitive) type, but not a class.

Hence: every class is a type, but not every type is a class.

Answer (score 0):

If we think to this question in C# context, we reach bellow answer.

C# type system is divided into following categories:

Value types:

- Simple types: like int, long, float, etc.
- Enum types
- Struct types
- Nullable types

Reference types:

- Class types
- Interface types
- Array types
- Delegate types

As you can see there are many types in C# which Class is only one of them.
There is just one important note:
C#’s type system is unified such that a value of any type can be treated as an object. Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the object class type, and object is the ultimate base class of all types. Values of reference types are treated as objects simply by viewing the values as type object. Values of value types are treated as objects by performing boxing and unboxing operations.

so as I see, type is an umbrella over many items which class is one of them.

Referece: CSahrp Language Specification doc, page 4

Answer (score -1):

This was a good question for me, which made me think hard. I would dare to say that Class is a compiletime thingy and Type is a runtime thingy. I say this because you write classes not types. The compiler then creates types from classes, and the runtime use types to create instances of objects.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer is very similar to at least one other and SO users prefer more technical language than 'thingy'!

Answer (score -1):

types are programming constructs that helps the compiler to perform type checking and ensure that the variables have the right properties for an operation.

classes are user defined types that an objects or variables referencing them could have. These are also subjected to type checking.