# Type alias for mix-in type

Tags: scala, types, mixins

Since I can do this:

```
case class A(a: Int)
trait C

val x = new A(10) with C
```

Why can't I do this:

```
type X = A with C
val x = new X(10)
```

? If I can't even construct an instance, what's the use case of `type X = A with C`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031640

Answer (score 1):

The error message that you get should give you a hint:

```
error: class type required but A with C found
              new X(10)
                  ^
```

`X`, as a type alias, gets rewritten to an `A with C` type expression, which is not a *class type*. The latter, according to the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), is:

> a type designator
>   (§
>   3.2.3
>   ) that **refers to a a class or a trait**

(emphasis mine)

In other words, it's not every type expression.

This is not an authoritative answer, but I don't believe it's possible to define a type alias in such a way that it becomes a *class type*. On the one hand, a `new` expression *theoretically* accepts an `AnnotType`, as defined in Section 5.1.1. However, I don't see how, using the type alias grammar from Section 4.3, you could specify what constructor are you using etc..

**tl;dr - unless your type alias is directly rewritable to a class type (e.g. `A` in your example), you can't use it as a class type, which includes invoking `new` with it. If you want that, you need a class declaration, i.e. `class X(a: Int) extends A(a) with C`.**

---

Regarding your second question, you say you can't instantiate `X`. Ah, but that's where you're wrong! Let me show you an example, based on your code:

```
def blah(x: X) = x.toString
val x = new A(10) with C
val y = new A(10)
blah(x) //String = A(10)
blah(y) //type error
```

So, **it's useful whenever you need a type constraint, since the "aliased" type will be matched to the type alias, even if it wasn't explicitly declared as such**.