# Why do we have a need for separate case identifiers in case of type only matching in scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

From [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html).

You can match on the type like so:

```
sealed trait Device
case class Phone(model: String) extends Device:
  def screenOff = "Turning screen off"

case class Computer(model: String) extends Device:
  def screenSaverOn = "Turning screen saver on..."


def goIdle(device: Device): String = device match
  case p: Phone => p.screenOff
  case c: Computer => c.screenSaverOn
```

It is a convention to use the first letter of the type as the case identifier (p and c in this case).

Question:

Why do we have a need for separate identifiers `p` and `c` here? Why cant we achieve the same with `device.screenOff` or `device.screenSaverOn` like in the case of a normal pattern matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both options are valid:

- [typed patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#typed-patterns)

```
def goIdle(device: Device): String = device match
  case p: Phone    => p.screenOff
  case c: Computer => c.screenSaverOn
```

- [constructor patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns) / [pattern binders](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders)

```
def goIdle(device: Device): String = device match
  case p@Phone(_)    => p.screenOff
  case c@Computer(_) => c.screenSaverOn
```

Imagine that `Phone` or `Computer` has many parameters. With the 2nd approach you'll be writing patterns like `Phone(_,_,_,....,_)`, `Computer(_,_,_,....,_)`.

If `device` has type just `Device` (not its subtype `Phone` or `Computer`) then `device.screenOff` or `device.screenSaverOn` doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for the laymanesque language - By normal pattern matching I meant all the other pattern matching available on the documentation page apart from matching on type only. Can you please give me an example where ```device has type just Device (not its subtype Phone or Computer) then device.screenOff or device.screenSaverOn doesn't compile.``` How can I have a ```Phone``` or ```Computer``` without creating the classes ```Phone``` and ```Computer```

Comment: @figs_and_nuts Probably instead of "creating classes" you meant "instantiating classes". You still can instantiate `Phone` or `Computer` but have variable `device` of type `Device`, e.g. `val device: Device = new Phone("Xiaomi")`, `val device: Device = new Computer("Hewlett-Packard")`, `val device: Device = null`, `val device: Device = ???`, `type T <: Device; val device: T = ???`. In such case `device.screenOff` or `device.screenSaverOn` doesn't compile because the type `Device` itself doesn't have these methods.

Comment: @figs_and_nuts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468145/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031640/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-type-in-scala-and-java https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

Comment: @figs_and_nuts https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/hYmDSS29T1SJjPEYJEDABg `val device: Device = new Phone("Xiaomi")` `value screenOff is not a member of Device`

Comment: @figs_and_nuts In `val device: Device = new Phone("Xiaomi")` `Phone` is the class of instance (dynamic type, known by JVM at runtime) but `Device` is the static type of variable (known by the compiler at compile time). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time

Comment: @figs_and_nuts surely you can define the variable of type `Phone` or `Computer`. Then the methods will be accessible. Or you can try to move the methods into the parent trait.

Comment: Thank god I asked this question. Unavailability of ```screenOff``` to ``device``` came as a surprise and all the links you have posted made me realise I am john snow of type and class understanding. I didn't know the rabbit hole went this deep. Going through the links. Thank you, kind sir!