# How to make the subclass arguments available in the abstract class for pattern matching in scala?

Tags: scala, methods, pattern-matching, overriding, algebraic-data-types

I have a class and two case subclasses:

```
abstract class C
case class C1(left: C, right: C, weight: Int) extends C
case class C2(weight: Int) extends C
```

I want to implement something like the following:

```
def weight(t: C): Int = {
    t match {
      case c1: C1 => l.weight
      case c2: C2 => c2.left.weight + c1.right.weight //this line doesn't let the code compile
    }
  }
```

The above code does not compile. says `left` and `right` do not have attribute `weight`. I am seeing this because C does not have a weight defined for it. Only `c1` and `c2` do. However, the class instances that I pass to the `weight` function would be either `c1` or `c2` and would definitely have weight.

It is actually a recursive weight summation on a tree that I can achieve with the following:

```
def weight(t: C): Int = {
    t match {
      case c1: C1 => l.weight
      case c2: C2 => weight(c2.left) + weight(c1.left)
    }
  }
```

But, I do not want to recurse and I do not think I should have to if the weight information is simply there available in the instance that I am passing in.

It is an assignment question that I am trying to solve and the signature of classes `C`, `C1` and `C2` are sacrosanct. I have tried modifying

```
abstract class C
```

to

```
abstract class C:
    val weight: Int = ???
```

However, this then starts raising issues with the `weight` variable in the `C1` and `C2` signatures and asks me to override it.

The one solution I tried and thought would work was creating a companion object:

```
abstract class CodeTree
object CodeTree:
  val weight: Int = ???
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree
```

But I think the companion objects are not inherited by the subclasses

- How do I achieve the desired outcome without having to recurse?
- More broadly, How do I endow an abstract class with -- *this particular field would always be available in the subclasses that inherit from me and hence it should be available statically with me and not fail compilation*?

Comment: `trait C { def weight: Int }` ?

Comment: Cant change the signature of the provided scaffold in the assignment. If I were to build the solution from scratch this is how I too would have attempted it. Thank you for the solution :)

Comment: @figs_and_nuts If you can't modify `C` you can add extension method https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4kb8WHWxSE23KKbCohlHkA https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html

Comment: @figs_and_nuts Or simply one more method https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4kb8WHWxSE23KKbCohlHkA/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add member `weight: Int` to `C`

```
abstract class C:
  def weight: Int
case class C1(left: C, right: C, weight: Int) extends C
case class C2(weight: Int) extends C
```

Then you can match typed patterns

```
def weight(t: C): Int =
  t match
    case c1: C1 => c1.left.weight + c1.right.weight
    case c2: C2 => c2.weight
```

or constructor patterns

```
def weight(t: C): Int = 
  t match 
    case C1(l, r, _) => l.weight + r.weight
    case C2(w)       => w
```

[Why do we have a need for separate case identifiers in case of type only matching in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677699/why-do-we-have-a-need-for-separate-case-identifiers-in-case-of-type-only-matchin)

Normally abstract members are `def`s and overriden with `def`/`val`/`lazy val` (`var` if necessary) in implementations.

Comment: Ahh.. I tried the same with ```var``` instead of ```def```. Thank you :)

Comment: @figs_and_nuts You should use `var`s only when you really need them (mutability)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `weight` to the superclass is the proper approach.
But then you actually have to *define* `weight` in `C1`, which results in your not needing the pattern matching to begin with.

```
abstract class C { def weight: Int }
case class C1(left: C, right: C) extends C { def weight = left.weight + right.weight } 
case class C2(weight: Int) extends C

def weight(t: C) = t.weight
```