# What is the relationship between class and type?

Tags: class, programming-languages, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Type and Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468145/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class)

What is the relationship between class and type? Or what are the relationships between class and type?

If you think defining the concepts class and type clarifies the answer, please include definitions.

Answer (score 0):

**Resuming:**

The basic relationship between those two concepts is that a class defines a type.

If you define the class `Car`, you're also defining a new type: `Car`.