# Java Inheritance: Distinguishing between the IS-A and the HAS-A relationships

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, terminology

According to my textbook, the ability of a class to extend another class is known as *inheritance*. A subclass inherits all the fields and methods of its superclass, along with the type of its superclass. According to page 294 of my textbook, "*Java Methods: Object-Oriented Programming and Data Structures*",

> Inheritance represents the **IS-A** relationship between types of objects. A 
>   superclass defines more general features of the objects of its subclass; a 
>   subclass defines additional, more specific features (fields and methods) 
>   and may override (redefine) some of the methods of the superclass.

After reading this passage, I have concluded that a class *John* **IS-A** *Person*, if *John* extends *Person* The textbook does not define the **HAS-A** relationship, but it is reasonable for me to conclude, if  *John* extends *Person*, that *Person* **HAS-A** *John*. This is logically consistent, and explains inheritance in a simple manner.

My instructor, however, assigned us a quiz over Class Hierarchies and Interfaces. The following questions are from the quiz.

> **Consider the following definitions**:

```
public class Brush implements Drawable{...}

public class Canvas extends JPanel
{
 private Brush currentBrush;
 ...
}

public class Painter extends Person
{
 private Canvas canvas;
 ...
}
```

> *True* or *False*?
>   Based on the code shown, the following describes a relationship between the objects:
>
> A *Canvas* **HAS-A** Brush

The answer provided by the instructor was *True*

> A *Person* **HAS-A** *Canvas*

The answer provided by the instructor was *False*

> A *Painter* **HAS-A** *Brush*

The answer provided by the instructor was *False*

The provided answers make sense in a general sense, but do not satisfy the logical conclusions I reached through reading the book and several other online sources. Who here is confused?

Comment: You are confused. A **has-a** relationship implies that one class contains fields of another. For example, a `Person` **has-a** `birthDate`. Note that a `Date` doesn't usually have a `Person`.

Comment: *has-a* is not the inverse of an *is-a* relationship, it is a different type of relationships. For example, a car *is a* means of transportation (inheritance), but it *has a* wheel and brakes (composition).

Comment: Look at [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Details).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you. That makes great sense. Have a nice day!

Comment: @RobinKrahl Thanks you for this definition. This makes much more sense now that I think about it.

Comment: @user1803551 Thank you for this link. The differences between inheritance and composition really make the issue extremely clear to me, now that I look back at it.

Comment: You're on a roll but don't stop there.  Next is [subtyping vs subclassing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072290).