# How to correctly call this functions within a namespace? c++

Tags: c++

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

namespace ProgramCall
{

  class Class1
  {
    public: int Sum(int A, int B)
    {
      return A + B;
    }

    public: float Sum(int A, float B)
    {
        return A + B;
    }
  };

  class Class2 : Class1
  {
    public:
      int Sum(int A, int B, int C)
      {
        return A + B + C;
      }
  };

}
int main() {
  int res = ProgramCall::Class1.Sum(1,2);
  cout << res;
}
```

The error message I get:

```
exit status 1
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:32: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
   int res = ProgramCall::Class1.Sum(1,2);
```

How can I solve this? I mean, how should I call these functions within classes within namespaces? I'm a beginner in c++(but good on C), any tips are appreciated.

Comment: `Class1` must be instantiated or its function `Sum()` marked as `static` - then you can call it with `ProgramCall::Class1::Sum(...)`.

Comment: You might be interested in the question [What is the difference between classes and object instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775226/what-is-the-difference-between-classes-and-object-instances).

Comment: The both comments were helpful. Ty!

Comment: Sidenote: You don't have to mark each and every member with an access specifier.

Answer (score 1):

`ProgramCall::Class1` is a type, not an object. Hence, `ProgramCall::Class1.Sum(...)` is incorrect.

You can create a temporary object and call `Sum` on it.

```
int res = ProgramCall::Class1().Sum(1,2);
//                           ^^^ constructs an object
```

---

On a different note ...

Use of

```
class Class2 : Class1
```

is perhaps an error. When you do that, `Class1` is a `private` base class of `Class2`. You won't be able to use:

```
int res = ProgramCall::Class2().Sum(1,2);
```

If that's the intent, leave your code as is. If you want to be able to use the above line, change `Class2` to:

```
class Class2 : public Class1 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually this code is only for syntax study purpose, so I'm testing different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't call a member function as `ClassName::method()` as long as it is not static, non-static methods are bound to an instance of a class, hence instantiating it first should work:

```
auto instance = ProgramCall::Class1();

int res = instance.Sum(1,2);
```

Second, for the problem you showed, I'd advice you to keep things in free functions. The sum methods don't need state, and there is no invariance that `Class1`  or `Class2` need to maintain. Though I don't know whether you plan to enriche these classes later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually this code is only for syntax study purpose, so I'm testing different possibilities.